# dijit.form.DateTextBox setting values

Tags: dojo

I have following text field with dojo dojo Date text type.

> dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
>   required="true"/>

I use the following code to set the dijit.form.DateTextBox  value

> dijit.byId('dtinv').attr('value',new
>   Date(tList[i].getAttribute("dtinv")))
>   ;

tList[i].getAttribute("dtinv") has value 2010-04-02

When the value is set, I see 4/1/2010. Always the date in dojo date box shows one day less.
Is there something I should take care?

Answer (score 5):

Dojo and Dijit process Dates in local time, not GMT, which itself may have been a poor design choice, but given this, if you use `dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString()` or pass the string "2010-04-02" as the value attribute in your HTML you will get April 2 at midnight in your local time.  Pass that to the Dijit and it will be happy.  Using the new ES5 Date constructor in Javascript will have different results:

(I'm in the Eastern timezone)

```
>>> new Date("2010-04-02")
Thu Apr 01 2010 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EST) {}
```

that defines a date in GMT.  However, the following object would work as expected with Dijit:

```
>>> new Date(2010, 3, 2)
Fri Apr 02 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EST) {}
```

Also, Javascript's new Date constructor is poorly defined when it comes to taking Strings.  I'm not sure if the result you're getting is consistent across all browsers.  You are advised to use `dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString("2010-04-02")` to get the corresponding Date object, or ES5 ISO date methods, where available in newer browsers.